# LINQ Entity Framework - COUNT AND QUERY

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

```
edmx file: OrderData:
ORDERID
SHIPMENT
DRIVER_ID
RECEIVE_NAME
```

we need to build a table and print for each DRIVER_ID
first column:DRIVER_ID
second column: how many rows with this DRIVER_ID
third column: how many rows with this DRIVER_ID and has RECEIVE_NAME not null

please show me how it can be done...i only managed to print a getquery:(

```
    SERVER.CS

    public class OrderDataRepository : BaseRepository<OrderData>
    {


        public class OrderDataResults
        {
            public long DriverId { get; set; }
            public int OrderCount { get; set; }
            public int OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull { get; set; }
        }




        public class OrderViewRepository : BaseRepository<OrderData>
        {
            public List<OrderDataResults> GetOrderDataResults()
            {
                return GetQuery().
                       Where(x => x.SHIPMENT != null).
                       GroupBy(o => o.DRIVER_ID).
                       Select(g =>
                                 new OrderDataResults
                                 {
                                     DriverId = g.Key,
                                     OrderCount = g.Count(),
                                     OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull =
                                                       g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
                                 }).ToList();
            }
        }







    CLIENT.ASPX.CS

    public partial class Control : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var rep = new OrderViewRepository();
            List<OrderDataResults> results = GetOrderDataResults();

**Error 12  The name 'GetOrderDataResults' does not exist in the current context
Error   11  The type or namespace name 'OrderDataResults' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
**
            DataViewer.DataSource = results;
            DataViewer.DataBind();

        }


    }


    WEBPAGE.ASPX
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="DataViewer">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited the answer according to the comments.
I would define a class to incorporate the results of your query first:

```
public class OrderDataResults // Or whatever you want to call it
{
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public int OrderCount { get; set; }
    public int OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull { get; set; }
}
```

From your server you can return a list of those:

```
public class OrderViewRepository : BaseRepository<OrderView>
{
    public List<OrderDataResults> GetOrderDataResults()
    {
        return GetQuery().
               Where(x => x.SHIPMENT != null).
               GroupBy(o => o.DRIVER_ID).
               Select(g =>
                         new OrderDataResults
                         {
                             DriverId = g.Key,
                             OrderCount = g.Count(),
                             OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = 
                                               g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
                         }).ToList();
    }
}
```

And when loading the page you can call the `GetOrderDataResults()` method and get your list:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rep = new OrderViewRepository();
    List<OrderDataResults> results = rep.GetOrderDataResults();

    DataViewer.DataSource = results;
    DataViewer.DataBind();
}
```

In order to see the results, just remove the `<Columns>` section from your `GridView` definition:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="DataViewer">
</asp:GridView>
```

And again, you will probably want to refactor this code and make some structural decisions on your own as soon as you get this code working (e.g. decide whether you want to return a list from your reporitory, etc).
Furthermore, you will probably want to customize the way your table looks, so you might want to look at the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) documentation. In your case it seems that you only want to display the data, so a simpler control (such as the [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)) might prove to be a better fit.

Comment: can you not use the getsomeresults function and show me how you use the above code without using the GetSomeResults...can you make ne function "count_drivers_orders" the code that i pasted was just for the example... this time i will paste all the code i have in the server.cs file

Comment: Your code uses my GetSomeResults function on the server side...i am searching for a way to replace that function and to retrieve only that table alone

Comment: **your code gave me the error: "Error 4 The name 'GetSomeResults' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: IQueryable<OrderView> results= rep.GetSomeResults();
notice, that line was missing in your code

Comment: Ok, I made another attempt to help you get the code working. You can give it a try and see if this helps.

Comment: mate,thank you very very much.. i'm sorry for the trouble but can you add(not delete or edit) the previous client side code that you pasted before - i want to learn from it how to use the client

Comment: I have added the errors i get above - please help me to fix them

Comment: @user1021182 - `add(not delete or edit) the previous client side code that you pasted before - i want to learn from it how to use the client` - you can see the previous versions of the post by clicking the link next to "edited" under the question (currently it reads edited `2 hours ago`, so you click on `2 hours ago`).

Comment: @user1021182 - `I have added the errors i get above - please help me to fix them` what errors do you mean now?

Comment: i just edited my original code for this qustion and marked the errors

Comment: btw, in the previous version i got the same error: Error 11 The name 'GetSomeResults' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user1021182 - Yes, sorry, of course it should read `rep.GetOrderDataResults()`, since it's a method of the `OrderViewRepository` class.